# Passing class pointer in to constructor for class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Working on a collaborative project (was hoping two would be easier than one - how wrong was I...?)

Basically, what we're trying to do is a bit like this:

```
class first
{
    first(int * num);
};

class second
{
    second(first * frst);
    first * frt;
};

first::first(int * num)
{

}

second::second(first * frst)
{
    frt = frst;
}
```

There is a bit of an issue though, we can't include our Core.h file, since that contains includes to the files we're already including (there is sense somewhere there). Short version is, we're having to do something a bit more like this:

```
#ifndef PLAYERSTRUCTURE
#define PLAYERSTRUCTURE
// DO NOT INCLUDE CORE IN THIS FILE

class Core;

struct PlayerMem
{
    int cid;
    int y, x, z;
};

class Player
{
public:
    Player::Player(Core * coar);
    Player::Player(void);
    Player::~Player(void);
};
#endif
```

The Core class is declared but not defined, will this cause issues if we try to access it from within the Player class, using Core->GetSomething() etc?

Thanks

Comment: *"Passing class reference in to constructor for class"* Where is the reference? -- The type of a pointer to an incomplete type is itself complete, you just may not dereference it.

Comment: Apologies, I've tried a lot tonight so for some reason references were in my mind. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forwarding declaration. It's OK.

When you can use `Core->GetSomething()` without any compilation error then it means class `Core` is defined and it's not an incomplete type. So, there is no issue to use it. Just make sure you're passing a valid pointer to `Core` when constructing `Player`.

Note: In your code you're passing a pointer to a class type not a reference.

Comment: That's great, I was slightly concerned that the forward declaration would cause issues later on, probably because I'm used to C#, in which forward declarations are just non existent. Final thing, I guess, is it possible to not have a default constructor (aka I don't want to risk letting someone call Player(), as it won't be able to acquire the required data to do anything)? Thanks :)

Comment: Remove `Player::Player(void)` and then you have not a default constructor anymore due to declaring an overload with at least one parameter (`Player(Core * coar)`).

Comment: More, you don't need those `Player::` prefix before methods within a class declaration. Remove them to make your code standard.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate this. After trying so many things I don't know what is right any more.

Comment: Sorry to harass you on this - I'm trying to remove the default constructors, but I'm getting an error when running this code:   `player = Player(this);` - Should I be calling differently?

Comment: Removing default constructor you can not have an object of `Player` and the assign `player = ...`. You must make the object like `Player player(this);`

Comment: That means I'd need to dynamically instantiate those particular classes, right? Thanks again